# ListView in ViewPager doesn't scroll or receive touch events

Tags: android, android-viewpager, xamarin.android

I have read lots of posts and blogs and several say that vertical scrolling of a ListView within a ViewPager should work by default.  I can't make that happen.  I have a ViewPager with two View pages.  A WebView and a ListView.  I can't get interaction with my list view to work but swiping works perfectly.

**layout is**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/teachingClass_questionZone_viewSwitcher_resultsSwitcher">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/teachingClass_questionZone_webView_chartResults"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ListView
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:id="@+id/teachingClass_questionZone_listView_performanceList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_rounded_corner_background_light"
            android:divider="@drawable/shape_divider_horizontal"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_list_row_rounded_corner" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Adapter is**

```
public class PagerAdapterResults : Android.Support.V4.View.PagerAdapter
        {
            public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(View container, int position)
            {
                int resId = 0;
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    resId = Resource.Id.teachingClass_questionZone_webView_chartResults;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    resId = Resource.Id.teachingClass_questionZone_listView_performanceList;
                    break;
                }
                return container.FindViewById(resId);
            }

            public override void DestroyItem(View container, int position, Java.Lang.Object @object)
            {
                ((Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager)container).RemoveView((View)@object);
            }

            #region implemented abstract members of PagerAdapter
            public override bool IsViewFromObject(View view, Java.Lang.Object @object)
            {
                return view == ((View)@object);
            }

            public override int Count {
                get {
                    return 2;
                }
            }
            #endregion
        }
```

Comment: That is because your webview is placed above your listView and is preventing it from recieving touch events. Also, it works with fragments, each viewpager page has its own set fragment with its own layout, which accounts for its children. Refer to the following link for more details: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html

Comment: Please for the love of what is holy do not use that kind of PagerAdapter. Use `Fragment`s instead!

Comment: That did it.  I thought about using Fragments but I thought I was starting to get carried away with all the Fragments I had so I thought I would try just using simple views and one Frag controller.  Thank you, works great now.

Comment: Using fragments in my ViewPager works nicely but it added a problem.  My ViewPager is contained within a Fragment not an Activity and when I detatch and reattach the same fragment within the Activity, my ViewPager is empty even though the adapter shows both fragments.

Comment: You need to do some handling of the state in the Adapter.